# How to get non-nullable data in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please refer below details

Current output:

```
EmpID   EmployeeDailyFee  EmployeeMonthlyFee  CompanyDailyFee  CompanyMonthlyFee
12      NULL              150                 NULL             NULL
12      120               NULL                NULL             NULL
```

Expected output:

```
EmpID   EmployeeDailyFee  EmployeeMonthlyFee  CompanyDailyFee  CompanyMonthlyFee
12      120               150                 NULL             NULL
```

Please let me know your suggestions

Comment: It's a lot easier to guess if you include a sampling of data in the database and the SQL statement yoyu're using to get those results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only get one non-null value in each column for each employee, you could try the following:

```
SELECT EmpID ,
       MAX(EmployeeDailyFee) AS EmployeeDailyFee,
       MAX(EmployeeMonthlyFee) AS EmployeeMonthlyFee, 
       MAX(CompanyDailyFee) AS CompanyDailyFee, 
       MAX(CompanyMonthlyFee) AS CompanyMonthlyFee
FROM Employees
GROUP BY EmpID
```

Comment: Be sure to use the right aggreate function though. Look into MAX, SUM, AVG etc.

Comment: @WeSt Based on OPs example, MAX seems to be the right one.

Comment: I agree. I just wanted to point out that there are different functions that can be used in that place.